# Unicode symbols coming wrong

Tags: php, html, unicode, entity

Obviously, there must be something stupid i'm doing. The unicode chart for subscripts and  superscripts says #00B2 is superscript 2, but i get scrambled output. 0078 is x, but I get N, and 0120 is x. Am i reading wrong manual?

---

EDIT

```
$x = '&#0078;';

print html_entity_decode($x, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\n";
```

Comment: can you post some code? which encoding you are using?

Comment: Sorry, Robert, all mind readers are on vacation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be confusing decimal and hexadecimal values. For example, hexadecimal 0x78 is lower-case x, but decimal 78 (hexadecimal 0x4e) is upper-case N.

In HTML, you can specify Unicode entities as either decimal using `&#n;` or as hexadecimal with `&#xn;` (where `n` is replaced with the decimal or hexadecimal character code). For a superscript 2, you'd could use either `&#178;` or `&#xb2;`.

In your example code, you are decoding the entity `&#0078;`. This is a decimal entity, so you get the expected result (upper-case N). The Unicode tables you've linked to use hexadecimal. To get a lower-case x, you would have to use `&#x0078;` as the input.

Comment: ok.. thts gr8.. &#178 works.. could you please tell me if the unicode chart i'm using is correct.. http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf . It says 00B2 is superscript 2.

Comment: @robert The chart is correct. 00B2 is in hexadecimal. If you use `&#x00B2;` you will get a superscript 2 (note the extra 'x').

Comment: @robert: aren't you missing 'x' to specify the hexadecimal value?

Comment: @robert being an official unicode chart, it is correct by definition.